# Beam / DataFlow ::ReadFromPubSub(id_label) :: Unexpected behavior

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Can someone clarify what's the purpose for `id_label` argument in [ReafFromPubSub transform](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py#L149)?

I'm using BigQuery sink, my understanding it acts like an `insertId` for BQ Streaming API, [Tabledata: insertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll)

> A unique ID for each row. BigQuery uses this property to detect duplicate insertion requests on a best-effort basis. For more information, see data consistency.

However I don't see this expected behaviour.

- I'm publishing messages to Pub/Sub, each message with same attribute `message_id` value (this is intentional to test pipeline / BQ dedupe behaviour)
- My pipeline reads from pubs as follows 
  `beam.io.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub(topic=TOPIC,
            subscription=None,
            id_label='message_id'`)

but still querying BQ, all messages get inserted. I expected, because each message published with same message_id value, BQ should have deduced those...

can someone clarify pls?
Thanks in advance!

Also, I notice `DirectRunner` keep throwing error when using this attribute,

> NotImplementedError: DirectRunner: id_label is not supported for PubSub reads

I've to use `DataflowRunner`... is that expected as well?

Cheers!

**UPDATE 1** : moved to DataflowRunner, and the pipeline seems to respect `id_label` argument during ReadFromPubSub(). **However, the duplicate messages DO continue to get read into the pipeline sporadically**.

- My publisher application, every 15 sec, publishes messages in following format ([the publisher app code is here](https://github.com/vibhorj/gcp/blob/master/df/so-55194499/pub.py)):

  cid=141&message_id=2&evt_time={{DATE_TIME_AT_RUNTIME}}

notice, i’m passing same `message_id` value (=‘2’) in message’s attribute as well (this is intention to try, test deduce behaviour).

- my pipeline (running on Dataflow Runner, beam Python v2.11 SDK, [pipeline code is here](https://github.com/vibhorj/gcp/blob/master/df/so-55194499/pipeline.py) ), dumps following message to BQ. As you can see, multiple messages with same `message_id` get read into pipeline and emitted to sink. This usually happens, when I stop/restart my publisher application.

```
cid=141&message_id=2&evt_time=2019-03-17T09:31:15.792653Z
cid=141&message_id=2&evt_time=2019-03-17T09:30:00.767878Z
cid=141&message_id=2&evt_time=2019-03-17T09:28:30.747951Z
cid=141&message_id=2&evt_time=2019-03-17T09:22:30.668764Z
cid=141&message_id=2&evt_time=2019-03-17T09:21:00.646867Z
cid=141&message_id=2&evt_time=2019-03-17T09:19:45.630280Z
cid=141&message_id=2&evt_time=2019-03-17T09:12:05.466953Z
cid=141&message_id=2&evt_time=2019-03-17T09:10:42.956195Z
cid=141&message_id=2&evt_time=2019-03-17T09:01:42.816151Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are different IDs. As explained [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage), every message published to a topic has a field named `messageId` that is guaranteed to be unique within the topic. Pub/Sub guarantees [at-least-once delivery](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#at-least-once-delivery) so a subscription can have duplicates (i.e. messages with the same `messageId`). Dataflow has [exactly-once processing](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/after-lambda-exactly-once-processing-in-google-cloud-dataflow-part-1) semantics because it uses that field to de-duplicate messages when reading from a subscription. This is independent of the sink, which does not need to be BigQuery.

Using `id_label` (or `.withIdAttribute()` in the Java SDK) we can force that messages are considered duplicate according to a different field that should be unique (such as order ID, customer ID, etc.). The input source will read the repeated messages only once, you won't see them increase the count of input elements in the pipeline. Keep in mind that the Direct Runner is intended for [testing](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/) purposes only and does not offer the same guarantees in terms of checkpointing, de-duplication, etc. As an example refer to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840154/how-to-deduplicate-messages-from-gcp-pubsub-in-dataflow-using-apache-beams-pubs?rq=1#comment86655718_47842113). That's the most likely cause of why you are seeing them in the pipeline, also taking into account the `NotImplementedError` messages, so I'd suggest moving to Dataflow Runner.

On the other side, `insertId` is used, on a [best-effort](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataconsistency) basis, to avoid duplicate rows when retrying streaming inserts in BigQuery. Using `BigQueryIO` it is created [under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54193825/6121516) and can't be specified manually. In your case, if your N messages enter the pipeline and N are written to BigQuery, it is working as expected. If any had to be retried, the row had the same `insertId` and was, therefore, discarded.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I moved to Dataflow Runner and things work as expected. Seems Direct Runner doe snot (yet?!) have support for `id_label` or `timestamp_attribute` for PubSub read source

Comment: Just to confirm Dataflow deduping happens at 'per window' level? if another window sees message with same 'id', it'll be processed in new window..

Comment: the duplicate messages DO continue to get read into the pipeline sporadically. pupated my original Q, with "UPDATE 1".

Comment: I did some tests and got more or less similar results (with windowing too). I'd like to mention that duplicates mainly come after the [10min window](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/pubsub-io) and that de-duplication with custom id attributes is also [best effort](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.py#L154) because it expects to remove accidental retries and not cases where the source actually contains duplicate records. For that. you might consider grouping by ID and discarding extra elements.

Comment: exactly-once processing within what timeframe (a job cannot remember all message IDs encountered)?